# Images not getting deleted from Appcelerator arrowdb

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-arrow

I am deleting image using appcelerator API

```
https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com/v1/photos/delete.json?key=<YOUR APP KEY>&pretty_json=true
```

After using this API image object gets deleted but if I hit URL of this image object then it still shows image. This is odd as my image is still present in database which I don't want.

I have waited for one day to check if it gets deleted after some time but without success.

Image was deleted by user who created this image.

Please help

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you providing your APP KEY when deleting? "message":"401 Unauthorized request. Please provide a valid App key or Oauth key." The app key is required. Reference http://docs.appcelerator.com/arrowdb/latest/#!/api/Photos-method-delete.

Comment: Hi Sharif..Thanks for replying. I am providing all details while deleting. I get 200 in response after I delete. Even if I query for that image using id it shows me no records meaning that image got deleted. But still if I use url for image (which I noted down before deleting) then image is still shown on that URL

Comment: If you get 200 but the image is still there, then it looks like you've found a bug. Please check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it's not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.